# Mac Terminal is displaying branch tags incorrectly

Tags: git, osx-elcapitan

[image: picture of my terminal]

I just updated to OSX El Capitan (mistake?) and my terminal is now behaving strangely. Whenever I'm on my master branch, it displays the "master" tag as the text above. Similarly, when I switch branches, the same thing happens (only "master" is replaced with the name of my feature branch).

What happened?

Comment: It's just your prompt that looks odd. What is the output of `echo "$PS1"`?

Comment: @chepner \n\[\033[0;31m\]\W\[\033[0m\]$(git_prompt)\[\033[0m\]:>

Comment: Somehow your color coding is not being parsed and shown as it is

Comment: It's missing some backslashes; should be `\n\[\033[0;31m\]\W\[\033[0m\]$(git_prompt)\[\033[0m\]:>`.

Comment: @chepner Any idea how I'd fix that? I'm very new to this.

Comment: Having your current branch display in your bash prompt is not "normal" on OS X.  At a guess, you had [bash-git-prompt](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt) installed, and the El Capitan update changed something about the installation.  I'd suggest checking the bash-git-prompt installation instructions to confirm what pieces might have been impacted by the update.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same issue:

I didn't find the solution to the original problem, but I did find a workaround. Just follow the instructions in [this article](http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac/) by Martin Fitzpatrick.